# How to handle "Error: Town not found" when updating an existing field with Field Calculator?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I want to update a field in field calculator.
update existing field is checked.
Column to be updated : Column2

```
CASE  
        WHEN "COLUMN1"  IS NOT NULL 
        THEN "COLUMN2" = "Town"
        ELSE "COLUMN2" = 0
END
```

Basically if Col1 has data I want Col2 to be town.
Error: Town not found.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is Town a column name or should it be the string 'Town' instead?

Comment: string called 'Town'

Answer (score 5):

Note that "Town" refers to a column called Town, while 'Town' is the string that you actually want to assign. Therefore:

(Updated to correct the then and else parts. Thanks fluidmotion for pointing out the issues.)

```
 CASE  
    WHEN "COLUMN1"  IS NOT NULL 
    THEN 'Town'
    ELSE  0
 END
```

Answer (score 3):

Similar to @underdark,
but in my installation, i had to use

```
 CASE  
    WHEN "COLUMN1"  IS NOT NULL 
    THEN 'Town'
    ELSE 0
 END
```

and be sure the correct update field is checked, as you mentioned.
when i attempted to set "COLUMN2" to some value with the CASE comparison, it will only evaluate true or false (0 or 1), rather than actually updating with the string value.

Comment: +1 and I've corrected my post ... was only paying attention to the when part ...